# Computing conditional distribution

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let us suppose we have continuous random variables $X \sim \mathrm{exp}(1)$ and discrete uniform random variable $Y \sim U(1,10)$. Generally, how could we compute the conditional distribution of $P(X|Y)$?

For example, how to compute $P(X-4 \le t|Y \ge 5)$?

If the case is good to compute, then if we take $Y\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$, then how could we compute

$$P(X-4 \le t|Y \ge 5)$$

Thank you guys for help. Really appreciate that.

Comment: You need to know their joint distribution or you have to assume the independence of $X$ and $Y$

Comment: Well here something is tricky, for joint distribution, is it necessary for both $X$ and $Y$ to be either continuous or discrete??? If not, then yeah we can assume independence of $X$ and $Y$ for the sake simplicity. But if the answer is yes, then it is even problematic for me to write out the joint......... Well, really thanks~~~~

Comment: Regarding the joint distribution, it's not a problem for $X$ to be continuous and $Y$ discrete. If you assume independence, $P(X \mid Y) = P(X)$, by definition. Otherwise, you need the joint distribution, as DeepNorth mentioned.